# How to configure AppArmor so that KVM can start guest that has a backing file chain

Tags: kvm, qemu, snapshot, apparmor

I'm playing around with using Qemu external snapshots for KVM (because they are so fast!) on Ubuntu 16.04 and have the following setup:

- All files for the VM are within a single directory (named after the guest).
- There is a `head.qcow2` symlink that always points to the top "head" qcow2 image. This way I don't have to keep updating the VM config. (virsh edit).
- The original/bottom image is called `base.qcow2`

I use the following script to take a snapshot (create a new qcow2 image and make it the head). The script is only executed when the guest is not running.

```
#!/bin/bash
UNIX_TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)
CURRENT_BACKING_FILE=`readlink head.qcow2`
NEW_HEAD_FILE="`pwd`/`echo $UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.qcow2"

# Create the new "head" disk image where all future changes are made.
sudo qemu-img create \
  -f qcow2 \
  -b $CURRENT_BACKING_FILE \
  $NEW_HEAD_FILE

# Update the symlink
rm head.qcow2
ln -s $NEW_HEAD_FILE head.qcow2
```

This will work fine when head.qcow2 points to base.qcow2, or I run the script **once** so there is only a single backing file. However, If there is a chain of backing files (e.g. a backing file also has a backing file), then I will get the following error:

```
error: Failed to start domain template-ubuntu-docker2
error: internal error: early end of file from monitor, possible problem: 2018-04-05T19:04:55.597373Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/head.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Could not open backing file: Could not open backing file: Could not open '/media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/base.qcow2': Permission denied
```

The output of `qemu-img --backing-chain head.qcow2` is:

```
image: head.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 196K
cluster_size: 65536
backing file: /media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/1522954330.qcow2
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false

image: /media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/1522954330.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 4.1M
cluster_size: 65536
backing file: base.qcow2 (actual path: /media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/base.qcow2)
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false

image: /media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/base.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 8.8G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

I've played around with deleting images or using qemu-img commit to merge them, and as soon as I go down to just one or two images the guest will start.

Since it looked like a permission error with "could not open" I tried setting permissions to 777 and I still get the same error message, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's related to AppArmor again (I had a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741035/disabling-apparmor-for-kvm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) some years ago on Ubuntu 14.04 that I forgot about). I was able to get it working by:

Installing apparmor-utils

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

Then find the libvirt ID in the most recent syslogs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep "apparmor" | grep "DENIED" | grep libvirt-
```

Then use that ID with the full path to set it to "complain mode".

```
sudo aa-complain \
/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-b0cd5bdf-6dfc-4f75-bc0f-e38adff1cdd2
```

Then start your guest.

This feels like a workaround at best and annoying if I have to do it for each guest individually. I would be happier if someone provided a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem on Debian Buster, the fact is that libvirt apparmor profiles are dynamically created and stored under /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/ (thanks @Programster). In this directory you should found a TEMPLATE.qemu similar to this one:

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile LIBVIRT_TEMPLATE flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
}
```

You should add rules for the directory where you store your qcow2 in the profile:

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile LIBVIRT_TEMPLATE flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
  /media/ssd_storage2/kvm/vms/templates/template-ubuntu-docker2/**.qcow2 rk,
}
```

"r" is for read permission and "k" is for lock permissions.

You can track apparmor audit messages with "dmesg -w", and get similar messages depending which permissions are missing:

```
[ 4404.140981] audit: type=1400 audit(1566342100.488:254): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-b24e7663-d71a-4970-9d6c-711d43629135" name="/home/libvirt/0.0.6-dev.19+20~811d1dc983b5.qcow2" pid=22384 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=64055 ouid=64055
...
[ 4652.827860] audit: type=1400 audit(1566342349.172:263): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_lock" profile="libvirt-b24e7663-d71a-4970-9d6c-711d43629135" name="/home/libvirt/0.0.6-dev.19+20~811d1dc983b5.qcow2" pid=23085 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="k" denied_mask="k" fsuid=64055 ouid=64055
```

Comment: That looks like a better solution. I tried this on Debian 10 with adding `/home/stuart/KVM-Command-Generator/vms/*.qcow2` but am now getting: error: internal `error: Process exited prior to exec: libvirt:  error : unable to set AppArmor profile 'libvirt-1556ff06-f26c-408c-bf9e-c339290e32e6' for '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you running as privileged or unprivileged user ? Don't known if this is important or not. But since I only tested as privileged user, who knows ?
A copy of your modified template may help also.

Comment: It took me much longer than I'd like to admit but for those who cannot find TEMPLATE.qemu `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu` :D